# acct.owner.email in Apex returns null

Tags: apex, relationships, reference

I have a simple class that loops thru the new versions of a list of Accounts.

However acct.owner.email returns null, while acct.ownerid returns the owner id.

Can I not transcend the owner relationship/reference to pull the owner email in Apex?

```
for(Account acct : newAcctList) {

        Account oldAcct = null;
        oldAcct = oldAcctsMap.get(acct.id);

        if(acct.ownerId != oldAcct.ownerId
           && acct.qual_field__c != null) {

            try{
                // qualify
                if((oldAcct.ownerId != contextUser)
                   && (profileIdSet.contains(contextProfile) != True)) {

                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        message.setToAddresses(new String[] {oldAcct.owner.email});
```

Comment: can you post your code please, if this in context of trigger you may have to query the owner.name while ownerid may be readily available in a trigger context.

Comment: how are you populating oldAcctsMap

Comment: @Rao Added my code, the last line references the owner email, same issue with it being null.

Comment: new versions and the old map are passed from a trigger to this class. oldAcct.ownerId does not come back null.

Comment: is this a before or an after tigger, it will be helpful if you can paste the complete trigger

Comment: Read through this post, short answer is you have to query the name data. Salesforce cannot look for relationship fields it will only fetch the fields in the trigger context http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/23/relationship-lookup-objects-in-triggers-are-null/

Comment: @Rao :(, read that. Was hoping I would not have to do that. Post it as the answer for credit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47016/discussion-between-rao-and-robert-e-lee).